# How to draw text on a sphere in javafx

Tags: javafx, text, javafx-3d

I want to draw a text onto a sphere in javafx.

I try to keep it purely javafx.
I'm using a `PerspectiveCamera`.

One option would be to just draw 3D-text (if that exists) touching the sphere and being parallel to the viewer for good readability. The better option would be to draw a curved text right onto the sphere, also facing the viewer.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1. Text3D**

There is no built-in JavaFX 3D Text node. However you can use a `Text3DMesh` node from the [FXyz](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/primitives/Text3DMesh.java) library.

Something like this:

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.fxyz3d:fxyz3d:0.4.0'
}

javafx {
    version = "12"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

mainClassName = 'text3d.Text3D'
```

*text3d.Text3D.java*

```
public class Text3D extends Application {

    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(10, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(-10, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    private double mousePosX, mousePosY, mouseOldX, mouseOldY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
        camera.getTransforms().addAll (rotateX, rotateY, new Translate(-100, 100, -1000));

        Text3DMesh text3D = new Text3DMesh("Text3D");
        text3D.setFont(Font.getFamilies().get(new Random().nextInt(Font.getFamilies().size())));
        text3D.setFontSize(200);
        text3D.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.y);
        Bounds bounds = text3D.getBoundsInParent();
        text3D.setTranslateX(- bounds.getWidth() / 2d);
        text3D.setTranslateY(bounds.getHeight() / 2d);
        text3D.setTranslateZ(-bounds.getDepth());

        double radius = Math.max(bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight()) * 1.2;
        SpheroidMesh spheroid = new SpheroidMesh(radius);
        spheroid.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.x * p.y);
        spheroid.setTranslateZ(radius);

        Group group = new Group(spheroid, text3D);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setFill(Color.BISQUE);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("FXyz3D Sample");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image: Text3D]

**Solution 2. Image**

Another approach can be done by adding an image as diffuse map of the sphere. Again, this can be done with FXyz.

First, you need to render a regular `Text` 2D node on a scene, and do a snapshot of it to generate the image.

*text3d.Image3D*

```
public class Image3D extends Application {

    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(10, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(-10, Rotate.Y_AXIS);

    private double mousePosX;
    private double mousePosY;
    private double mouseOldX;
    private double mouseOldY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
        camera.setFieldOfView(20);
        camera.getTransforms().addAll (rotateX, rotateY, new Translate(-100, 100, -2000));

        Text text = new Text(" Text3D ");
        text.setStroke(Color.DARKGOLDENROD);
        text.setFill(Color.DARKGOLDENROD);
        text.setFont(Font.font(Font.getFamilies().get(new Random().nextInt(Font.getFamilies().size())), 30));
        Group root = new Group(text);
        Scene sceneAux = new Scene(root, root.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth(), root.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight());
        SnapshotParameters sp = new SnapshotParameters();
        double s = Screen.getPrimary().getOutputScaleX();
        sp.setTransform(new Scale(s, s));
        sp.setFill(Color.DARKMAGENTA);
        Image image = root.snapshot(sp, null);

        double radius = 400;
        SpheroidMesh spheroid = new SpheroidMesh(radius);
        ((PhongMaterial) spheroid.getMaterial()).setDiffuseMap(image);
        Group group = new Group(spheroid);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setFill(Color.BISQUE);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("FXyz3D Sample");
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

[image: Image3D]

**EDIT**

**Solution 3**

While this is not part of FXyz, you can also apply some transforms to wrap the `Text3DMesh` around the sphere.

Each letter basically is a `TriangleMesh` with a translate transform in X (`offset`).

So we take all the points for each letter, remove the transform, and apply the offset, so we have absolute coordinates:

```
 x = x + offset;
```

Then we calculate the bending angle based on a given arc length we want and the actual width `w` of the text node.

```
 t = (x - w/2) / (w/2) * Pi/2;
```

Then, for each point, its new coordinates will be:

```
 x = (R + z) * cos(t);
 z = (R + z) * Sin(t);
```

*text3d.CurvedText3D.java*

```
public class CurvedText3D extends Application {

    private final Rotate rotateX = new Rotate(10, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    private final Rotate rotateY = new Rotate(-10, Rotate.Y_AXIS);

    private double mousePosX, mousePosY, mouseOldX, mouseOldY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setNearClip(0.1);
        camera.setFarClip(10000.0);
        camera.setFieldOfView(40);
        camera.getTransforms().addAll (rotateX, rotateY, new Translate(-100, 100, -2000));

        Text3DMesh text3D = new Text3DMesh("Round Text3D",
                Font.getFamilies().get(new Random().nextInt(Font.getFamilies().size())), 100, true);
        text3D.setHeight(30);
        text3D.setTextureModeNone(Color.CRIMSON);
        Bounds bounds = text3D.getBoundsInParent();
        double width = bounds.getWidth();

        double radius = Math.max(width, bounds.getHeight());

        text3D.getMeshes().stream()
                .forEach(m -> {
                    ObservableFloatArray points = ((TriangleMesh) m.getMesh()).getPoints();
                    float[] v = new float[points.size()];
                    points.toArray(v);
                    double offset = m.getTransforms().get(0).getTx();
                    m.getTransforms().clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i += 3) {
                        v[i] += offset;
                        double t0 =  (v[i] - width / 2d) / (width / 2d) *  Math.PI / 2;
                        double t1 = (radius + v[i + 2]) * Math.cos(t0);
                        double t2 = (radius + v[i + 2]) * Math.sin(t0);
                        v[i] = (float) t1;
                        v[i + 2] = (float) t2;
                    }
                    ((TriangleMesh) m.getMesh()).getPoints().setAll(v);
                });

        SpheroidMesh spheroid = new SpheroidMesh(radius * 0.9);
        spheroid.setTextureModeVertices3D(1530, p -> p.x * p.y);

        Group group = new Group(spheroid, text3D);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 400, 300, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setFill(Color.BISQUE);
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            mousePosX = event.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = event.getSceneY();
            rotateX.setAngle(rotateX.getAngle() - (mousePosY - mouseOldY));
            rotateY.setAngle(rotateY.getAngle() + (mousePosX - mouseOldX));
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("FXyz3D Sample");
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

[image: Curved text 3d]

Comment: Looks very good, but is there really no way to use only javafx? Even in a very hacky way?

Comment: Or maybe even with awt/swing?

Comment: What do you mean with “only JavaFX”? FXyz is a pure JavaFX library. It is not part of the built-in JavaFX modules, so you have to add it as a third party dependency (via Maven/Gradle or adding the jar) to your project.

Comment: @jackjuni When you know what you are doing it is possible to do all that without any additional library. You only have to understand how the TriangleMesh works and then apply some math to get the transforms right. But why would you insist on doing all that if a libary can make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

One idea that comes to my mind is to render the text normally in an appropriate node like (TextField/Area/Flow) and then take a snapshot of this node. The resulting image could then be used as a texture to wrap around your sphere.